# Warning Message Illegal offset type from Where function Mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, offset

I receive this error in the top of view (even the view loads properly with data as expected)

A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Warning Message: Illegal offset type Filename:
>   database/DB_query_builder.php Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp64\www\procurement_v_alpha1\application\models\Notifications.php
>   Line: 32 Function: where

My model looks like,

```
public function user_alert ()
    {
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata['logged_in'];
        $role = $session_data['role'];
        $dept = $session_data['dept'];

        $data_user = array(
            'role' => $role,
            'dept' => $dept
        );

        $role = $data_user['role']; 
        $this->db->from('notification');
        $this->db->select('pr_id,item_name,dept_division');
        $this->db->where($role, 0); 

        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query -> result_array();
    }
```

Can you guys help me out with this?
is something wrong with using 'where' method?

Comment: it should be `role` not `$role`

Comment: Yes but it's a variable, it changes according to user. so there is a column for every 'role' i need to select that column. it worked fine before without session data. But now I'm getting this error

Comment: But I think its field name which should be same for every user and `$role` should have value. So it should be `('role',$role)`. For more details can you add your table structure ?

Comment: Try   `$this->db->where('role', '0'); ` if not try `$this->db->where('role', $role); `

Answer (score 0):

The userdata() method returns NULL if the item you are trying to access does not exist. Can this be the case? Maybe you must ad some isnull check.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `where` method wrong.

The function parameters are as following: `$this->db->where('columnName', 'value');`

So you should be using it like: `$this->db->where('role', $role);`
If you want to search for notifications where the `role` is `0`, then you should use `$this->db->where('role', 0);`

Source: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Answer (score 0):

something wrong here. `$this->db->where($role, 0);
$role` have some data given here `$role = $data_user['role']` But In where clause we need to give field name But you try To pass role values in where clause 
Make it some thing like this.

```
$this->db->where('role', 0)
```

Write Field Name in place of`'role'` you want to check.